# How to keep alarm silent during a phone call on my iPhone6?

Tags: notifications

How can I keep alarms I have set from going off during a telephone conversation?  I may set an alarm to go off tomorrow at 3:15 pm.  If I receive a phone call at 3:12 pm, I don't want the alarm to go off during the phone call.

Answer (score 1):

Alarms are automatically silenced by a phone call. The alarm will still go off, being displayed on the screen, but no noise or vibration will occur.